# Can I validate a HTML input without using JS and HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, legacy

I am creating a site for legacy mobile browsers (e.g.: browsers running on Nokia 2760), and cannot, of course, use JS nor HTML5. Is there any way to restrict user's input to prevent them to send letters in a numeric field? Or the best I can do is to execute a server-side validation?

Thanks!

Edit: I would like to have both client and server-side validation, not only the server-side one. 
It is desirable for me to restrict user's input, just like an `<input type="numeric" />` does. Tyiping several numbers in a old cellphone without that feature is painful.

The doctype I am using is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.0//EN” “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic10.dtd”>
```

Comment: You should always have server-side validation anyway... If anyone disables JavaScript on their browser, your validation goes out the window.

Comment: I edited the question so it's more clear, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Server side if your only option here.

JavaScript and the new features introduced in HTML 5 are the only client side options, and you've ruled them out.